# Entity Repository Method not found

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've some trouble with an method Repository.
I want to find all user from city (address) from province form the state.
I thought it's was good to divide all request method in Repository for more reusability.
I call :

```
$addr_repo = $this->getEntityManager()
                 ->getRepository('BtpUserProBundle:Address');
$address[$key] = $addr_repo->findByProvince($province->getId());
```

and my method findByProvince:

```
namespace Btp\UserProBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
* AddressRepository
*
* This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
* repository methods below.
*/
class AddressRepository extends EntityRepository
{

public function findByProvince($province_id)
{
    var_dump("lol");
    $ret = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT a FROM Btp\UserProBundle\Entity\Address a JOIN a.province p WHERE p.id = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $province_id)
        ->getResult();        

    var_dump($ret);     
    return $ret;
}
```

Address:

```
* @ORM\Table(name="address")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Btp\UserProBundle\Repository\AddressRepository")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Address {//somethink}
```

"lol" is not display. But I haven't any error.
Another question; do you think it's bad practice to use Repository in  another Repository (conceptually speaking)

Thanks

Comment: Please show me the top of your class implemented `findByProvince` method. I mean about namespace and class name.

Comment: first, get used to call `getManager()` since `getEntityManager()` is deprecated. For the other question yes, it's a bad practice, you should explain what you want to achive by using a repository in another repository.

Comment: `* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Btp\UserProBundle\Repository\AddressRepository")
* @ORM\Entity` try to remove the second `@ORM\Entity`

Comment: No, it's not *necessarily* a bad practice to use another repository as long as the entity has a relationship with the one you need (e.g: `CommentRepository::findByUser(User $user)`). However, you shouldn't make a repository *depends* on another repository. (`CommentRepository::__construct(UserRepository $users)`)

Comment: Ho! thanks it was that! I remove the second Entity and it's working! But your sure this is bad practice? (see my edit)

Comment: @JulienLeray i made an answer since it was helpful and it solved your issue. It may help others as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned in my comment, you should remove the second `@ORM\Entity` in your `Address` class declaration

```
* @ORM\Table(name="address")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Btp\UserProBundle\Repository\AddressRepository")
* @ORM\Entity <---- remove this
*/
```

Comment: But why it's bad practice to do that?

Comment: It's no bad practice, it's just wrong. By giving a second `Entity` metadata, you're overriding the first one. Hence, it didn't load your custom repository

Comment: I talk about use Repository in another Repository. I already understand that mistake ^^.

Comment: @JulienLeray you should explain what you want to do using a Repository in another Repository, because maybe there are some better ways to do it :)

Comment: I write what I want to do at the begining. I've UserRepository, AddressRepository, ProvinceRepository and StateRepository. I want all User who are in the address who is in the provinces who is in the state. The better way is to write one big method request in UserRepository, or cut in little method request in each other corresponding repository, and use them for the method in UserRepository. I hope i'm understandable :)

Comment: in this case yes, it would be a bad practice since this can be done with a single Query. You must build a query and JOIN all the entities you need. That would be definitely a better solution the split it in 3 different method and using a Repository in another one.